# ValueError when i try to visit the dashbord of my app (( Cannot query "adivaumar@domain.com": Must be "FriendList" instance.))

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here is my dashboard view.py the error I think is coming from the user_data instance, I just couldn't think of a way to go about it. I have also search on stack overflow for solutions but they happens to be different issue but the same Value error. what could possibly be the problem with my code?

```
def dashboard(request, session_username):
    user_videos = VideoPost.objects.filter(
                 user__username=request.user.username).order_by('-id')
    user_data = User.objects.get_or_create(
                          user=User.objects.get(
                            username=request.user.username))[0]
    user_video_likes = 0
    user_videos_views = 0

    for video in user_videos:
        user_video_likes += video.likes.count()
        user_videos_views += video.video_views.count()


    params = {'videos': user_videos, 
                  'user_data': user_data, 
                  'total_likes':user_video_likes, 
                  'total_views': user_videos_views}

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well so i was basically able to figure the problem out, which was i needed to import the FriendList  object and making an instance of it instead of using the User model.
Replacing the user_data object with FriendList object and it worked

```
def dashboard(request, session_username):
    user_videos = VideoPost.objects.filter(
                 user__username=request.user.username).order_by('-id')
    user_data = FriendList.objects.get_or_create(
                          user=User.objects.get(
                            username=request.user.username))[0]
```